# Iteratively subtracting a double (0.5) from an int does nothing once the int is zero.

Tags: java, loops

I've got a loop which subtracts a `double` (0.5) from an `int` with each iteration, which work just fine  until the `int` hits 0. Why doesn't the value go below 0?

Here's an example of my code:

```
int decrease = 2

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    System.out.println(decrease);
    decrease -= 0.5;
}
```

output:

```
2    
1    
1    
0    
0    
0
```

Can anyone tell me some alternatives to this, or if I'm doing something wrong? Because I really need an integer to decrease by less than 1 and I know that an `int` can be negative.

Comment: Start decrease at 4 and decrease it by 1.5 each time, that might make clearer what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my output, with only one `2` and one `1`.

```
2
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

The compound assignment operators, of which `-=` is one example, cast their result back to the variable type on the left side.  The [JLS, Section 15.26.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), states:

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

This means that for the actual subtraction, the value of `decrease` will be promoted to `double` for subtracting `0.5` (a `double` literal), but the difference value will be narrowed back to an `int` prior to assignment back to `decrease`.

The [JLS, Section 5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) covers this primitive narrowing conversion.

> A narrowing conversion of a floating-point number to an integral type T takes two steps:
>
> 1. In the first step, the floating-point number is converted either to a long, if T is long, or to an int, if T is byte, short, char, or int, as follows:
>
>    - If the floating-point number is NaN (§4.2.3), the result of the first step of the conversion is an int or long 0.
>    - Otherwise, if the floating-point number is not an infinity, the floating-point value is rounded to an integer value V, **rounding toward zero** using IEEE 754 round-toward-zero mode (§4.2.3).  ...

(emphasis mine)

The first subtraction yields `1.5`, which is rounded towards 0 to `1`.  The second subtraction yields `0.5`, which is rounded towards 0 to `0`.  Any subsequent subtraction yields `-0.5`, which is rounded towards 0, back to `0`.

To avoid this behavior, `decrease` should be a floating-point type.

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with the way rounding happens in integers.  What's happening is that the decrease value is being converted to a double precision value, 0.5 is being subtracted from it, and it is being converted back into an integer.

Integers always round towards zero.  So, while "decrease" is greater than zero, subtracting 0.5 makes it smaller, but once it is zero or negative, it stops.

Comment: Nice and succinct. I might add that providing a solution (e.g. use a floating-point type) would be a useful addition to the answer.

Comment: Your answer was very easy to understand and gave me a clear understanding of why this happened. Thanks mate!

Comment: Thanks, MatMat.  Re: Keith: Yeah, I realized that after I saw rgettman's response.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a float for `decrease` variable ? And then cast/convert/floor/ceil it to an integer ?

Comment: That would avoid the issue, but it wouldn't explain it, and I think it's useful to understand why this is happening, even if in "real" code, one would do what you suggest.